# Limit on response posts?

Tags: support, character-limit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there maximum character limits in comments and posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71283/why-are-there-maximum-character-limits-in-comments-and-posts)

I know this is similar to another post, but that post is talking about original posted questions.  My question is about responses or answers.

When responding to questions or answers here in SO, how can I post large blocks of code? There seems to be a 500+ cap on responses.

Comment: Do you mean comments? There's a 600 character limit on comments, and comments should not contain large blocks of code anyway. If answers, you can post reasonably large blocks of code in answers, but answers also have a length limit (30K iirc).

Comment: @DanielFischer answers allow 30K at least - [this is an example with about 29,9 K size](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/108298/31260 "shameless self-promotion")

Comment: @gnat I know more or less, I have [a 25K answer myself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9704912/1011995). I seem to recall that I read somewhere the limit was 30K, but I'm not 100% sure of that.

Comment: If you wish to show more code you are using to someone who is helping you it is much more beneficial to post the code as an edit to your original post.

Comment: I should link that answer more often in completely unrelated comments. I got an upvote there just a few seconds after linking it :D

Comment: *similar to another post* -- which other post?

Comment: Indeed, @Daniel, [30k I think](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/139319#139319).

Comment: @Arjan [You do indeed get the error as the link post suggests](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7oSbF.png)

Comment: reasons for post char limit are discussed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14142/165773), for comments char limit - [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71283/165773)

Answer (score 2):

> There seems to be a 500+ cap on responses.

Those are comments. Comments are not *answers*. Answers are posted by pressing the "Post Your Answer" button.

If you need to make a 600+ character long comment, then you're using the comment system wrong. Comments are for asking for clarification from a question/answer, or otherwise trying to improve a question/answer. They are *not* for engaging in discussion. If you're writing a comment that needs a code block, again you're doing it wrong.

If you're answering someone's question, you post an answer. That's your answer to the question. If you need to correct someone else's answer, don't do it in a comment (unless it's a small thing). You should add *your own answer* instead. You don't talk about the wrong answer in your answer either; you just post the correct answer. And probably downvote the incorrect one, possibly leaving a comment explaining where they went wrong.